# Question regarding construction of a linear nonzero bounded operator $T$ such that $T^2=0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am supposed to construct a nonzero bounded linear operator on a a separable Hilbert space of dimension at least 2 such that $T^2=0$. I have seen a question related to this (I don't know how to reference it) but for that question I saw that someone proposed the following operator $Te_1=e_2$ and $Te_n=0$ for $n\geq 2$ where $\{e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis for the Hilbert space. I can clearly see that this satisfies $T^2=0$ and that it's bounded, but I can't quite see whether it is linear? Can someone help me see whether it is or not?

Also if the Hilbert space is separable, is there another way of constructing such an operator? I would think one would have to use something with orthogonal complements.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One can always define a linear map by just saying where the basis vectors go. Indeed, if $\{e_i\}$ is a basis and we declare that $T(e_i) = v_i$, then one can easily check that the map $a_1e_1 + ... + a_ne_n \mapsto a_1v_1 + ... + a_nv_n$ is linear. Here, we express a vector using its basis representation. So in your case, you said that $T(e_1) = e_2$ and 0 for the other basis vectors. Now just define that on your whole vector space as I explain above. This is what is meant by "extending by linearity".

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! So you say that I should define that T maps $a_1e_1+...+a_ne_n$ to $a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n$?

Comment: Yes. Technically, you are defining the map $T$ just on the basis vectors and extending it to the whole space via this process. So to be pedantic, you can define a new map $\tilde{T}$ such that $\tilde{T}(a_1e_1 + ... + a_ne_n) := a_1T(e_1) + ... + a_nT(e_n) = a_1v_1 + ... + a_nv_n$

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense!

Comment: Np, glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M=\text{span}(e_{n})$, then $M$ is a vector subspace of the Hilbert space with Hamel basis $(e_{n})$, a linear operator on $M$ is uniquely determined by assigning the values to those $e_{n}$. The $T$ that created is clearly bounded on $M$, since $\overline{M}$ is the Hilbert space, now you can use bounded extension theorem to obtain a uniquely defined $T$ on the whole Hilbert space.